# Spring Security request.getUserPrincipal() always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

A really strange situation is observed in our application (Spring Boot 1.5.6 with all-default BOM dependencies): you can perfectly log in (with `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`), but this still leaves `Principal` in request `null`! I.e. `request.getUserPrincipal()` is `null` while `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is not!

This in turn affects the ability of our health endpoint to be sensitive: it uses `Principal` (see *HealthMvcEndpoint.exposeHealthDetails(HttpServletRequest, Principal)*) which is injected by `ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`, which in turn takes it from the request...

Looks like I'm missing something simple, but still can't find it :(

Comment: Why not just put debugger right in `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter` and see what Spring does with principal?

Comment: @tsolakp, the question is not what does Spring do with Principal (althought debugging it was the first thing I did). The question is: who is supposed to set it into the request? Or (if reworded) is it a bug in Spring to use Principal instead of Authentication in HealthMvcEndpoint?

Comment: If Spring has authenticated the request then the request had appropriate data for principal and Spring needs to set it. By looking at the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` I see quite a bit of logic that determines how principal is handled. You need to step through it and see how it is executed.

Comment: @tsolakp, I'm asking because I don't see it and the `Principal` doesn't get into the request, not because I'm a lazy asshole %) If you indeed look into `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(..)` - it does nothing except for calling `successfulAuthentication(..)` which in turn only sets the `Authentication` into Spring's security context (nothing else because there are no event publishers and success handlers at least in my case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after creating a new Spring Boot application and debugging it to its guts, I've found out that nobody actually sets `Principal` into the request. It's Spring who wraps it into another one that uses Spring's `SecurityContext` for the above (and some other methods). And this wrapping is done by the `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, which is there by default (see `HttpSecurity.servletApi()`)...

But somebody has disabled the default Spring Security configuration for our project, so the filter was not there!